# how to disable checkbox depending on data using vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to disable checkbox if the status in the API data is  `NOK`. I have given api data below. I am using VUEJS.

Serial number
      Pole ID
      Select All
        
        
      
    
  

                    
                      
                      {{pole.pole}}
                     {{pole.address}}

//api Data

```
            [
              {
                 "pole":"BNG-JAY-137-003",
               "address":"Jayanagar 4th Block Banglore",
               "status":"NOK"
                },
                {
                     "pole":"BNG-JAY-137-004",
               "address":"Jayanagar 5th Block Banglore",
               "status":"NOK"
                },
                {
                     "pole":"BNG-JAY-137-005",
               "address":"Jayanagar 6th Block Banglore",
               "status":"OK"
                }
            ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could bind the attribute `disabled` with your API status.

```
<input type="checkbox" :disabled="pole.status == 'NOK'" :value="pole.status == 'NOK' ? false : pole.pole" v-model="selected_data[pole.pole]">
```

Comment: but when i check all then it selects all checkbox(even disabled also checked)

Comment: I think its because your `:value` is there. The checkbox will be checked if a value exist. What you desire to get is: If status == 'NOK', then checkbox disabled and remain uncheck, right?

Comment: I guess I made a mistake, please try again with the above answer :)

Comment: <input type="checkbox" :disabled="pole.status == 'NOK'" :value="pole.status == 'NOK' ? false : pole.pole"   v-model="selected_data[pole.pole]">                                                             //sbro not working ...please check this once